# How to run 3 parallel tasks but not wait for each result to return?

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 download tasks

```
@State private var imageURL1: String
@State private var imageURL2: String
@State private var imageURL3: String

Button {
    Task {
        async let first = download(url: one)
        async let second = download(url: two)
        async let third = download(url: three)

        imageURL1 = await first
        imageURL2 = await second
        imageURL3 = await third
    }
}
```

I want to set the States as soon as they arrive back, not all 3 of them at the same time. How can I do that?

Comment: TaskGroup is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

To update the state as each download completes, just prefix each one with `await`…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var imageURL1: String = ""
    @State private var imageURL2: String = ""
    @State private var imageURL3: String = ""
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("GO!") {
                Task {
                    isLoading = true
                    await imageURL1 = download(url: "one")
                    await imageURL2 = download(url: "two")
                    await imageURL3 = download(url: "three")
                    isLoading = false
                }
            }
            
            Label(imageURL1, systemImage: "1.circle")
            Label(imageURL2, systemImage: "2.circle")
            Label(imageURL3, systemImage: "3.circle")
            
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func download(url: String) async -> String {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        return url
    }
}
```

[image]